# What's the right way to send one-off event from viewmodel to composable to show dialogs

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Channel and Flow to send one-off events from ViewModel to Fragment and Activity to make UI changes, such as showing dialogs. This doesn't seem working (or I may missed something in the logic) when creating UI with composables.

In my app, when the viewmodel performs some tasks, I need to send an one-off event to UI to show a dialog, such as the AlertDialog composable. The dialog is dismissed by setting a boolean with MutableState as in the official tutorial. But, when I send the event again, the MutableState value stays false and the dialog cannot be shown again.

Could anyone tell me the right way of sending one-off event and updating UI in Android Compose, please.

Comment: "But, when I send the event again, the MutableState value stays false and the dialog cannot be shown again." - Why does it stay false? Presumably your event would set it to true to have the dialog show again. Maybe show some code.

Comment: once you change value to false, then you have reset the value to true (vice versa) then it will work. If you apply every time same value ex: false, as the value does not changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommendation for this is to use Events as State.

In your state, you would define something like this

```
data class MyState(
    val showDialog: Boolean
)
```

then when you want to show the dialog, you update your state to have the `showDialog` flag set to `true`.

In the UI you would observe this flag and, when it toggles to `true`, you would show the dialog. When the user dismisses the dialog, you call a method in the viewmodel that toggles the flag back to `false`, like shown here, so the dialog goes away

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MyState>(MyState(showDialog = false))
    val state: StateFlow<MyState>
        get() = _state.asStateFlow()

    // call this when you want to show the dialog
    fun onShowDialog() {
        _state.update { state ->
            state.copy(showDialog = true)
        }
    }

    fun onDismiss() {
        _state.update { state ->
            state.copy(showDialog = false)
        }
    }
}

data class MyState(
    val showDialog: Boolean
)

@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    MyScreen(
        state = state,
        onDismiss = viewModel::onDismiss,
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    state: MyState
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    // other stuff

    if (state.showDialog) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            buttons = { /*TODO*/ },
            title = { /*TODO*/ },
            text = { /*TODO*/ },
        )
    }
}
```